# EKS Load Balancer Controller did not create the Load Balancers

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, load-balancing, amazon-eks

I have created a load balancer controller and it was created successfully. However, only the controller is created, not the load balancers. I tried changing the IAM roles for the node group, also reinstalled the helm release, but those didn't help either. Here is my configuration.

```
helm install aws-load-balancer-controller eks/aws-load-balancer-controller \
>   -n kube-system \
>   --set clusterName=LiveKit \
>   --set serviceAccount.create=false \
>   --set serviceAccount.name=aws-load-balancer-controller
```

The add-ons are fine, the nodes are ready and my VPC meets all requirements.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "only the controller is created, not the load balancers"?
LoadBalancers will get created when you deployed an ingress with `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb`(default value) annotation.Something like this.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "2048-ingress"
  namespace: "2048-game"
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
  labels:
    app: 2048-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: "service-2048"
              servicePort: 80
```